# Question about simply connected regions in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

If given the vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=\langle\frac{1}{x}+2xy,\frac{1}{y}+x^2-\cos{y}\rangle$, it is clear that the component functions are continuous everywhere expect at the origin.

Now, when asked to sketch the largest $\mathit{simply \, connected}$ region, let's call it $D$, which contained the point $P(-1,-2)$ on which $\mathbf{F}$ is continuous, I am getting slightly tripped up.

Because, to my understanding, if the component functions of $\mathbf{F}$ were continuous everywhere, we could conclude that the largest simply connected region containing $P$ on which $\mathbf{F}$ is continuous would be $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Yet, with the domain restriction on $\mathbf{F}$, the origin would be, for lack of a better term, a "hole" and therefore would make $\mathbb{R}^2$ not simply connected.

I can sketch a simply connected region containing said point on which $\mathbf{F}$ is continuous, yet I don't seem to understand how one would find and/or sketch the $\mathbf{largest}$ region fulfilling said conditions.

Would the location of $P$ have any affect on the size or location of this region?

I apologize if my notation is poor, so please feel free to correct it at any time because I am big on using proper notation wherever applicable.

Thank you,

Sam

Comment: Hint: neither $x$ nor $y$ can be zero.  Why?

Comment: "the component functions are continuous everywhere expect at the origin." Really?

Comment: Well if $x$ and/or $y$ were equal to zero, it would make one or both of the component functions undefined and therefore not continuous. I am having trouble finding information in regards to when there are discontinuities within the component functions.

Comment: But as @MichaelBurr suggests, each component has an entire line on which it's not defined

Comment: zhw- oops, right before you just posted your comment I realized that not only the origin is undefined, any point where $x=0$ or $y=0$ namely the coordinate axes.  Does this mean that $D=\{(x,y)| x<0,y<0\}$ would be the largest simply connected region fulfilling said conditions?

Comment: You can answer that question yourself: Is $D$ simply-connected? yes. Does it contain $P$? yes. Can $D$ be enlarged while remaining simply connected? No - any larger set is not even connected, much less simply connected.

Comment: @PaulSinclair ahh, I see.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MichaelBurr - thank you for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: @zhw thank you for your help! Much appreciated.